# Error in Woocommerce When Trying to Create Freight Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to develop a custom freight calculation plugin in Woocommerce, however I can not return the customer's typed zip to activate my formulas. In this example, I put just a basic formula to test, but it is causing the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Test_Shipping_Br::get_items_needing_shipping() in ...\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-cart.php on line 1316" when you go to the cart after a added product.

I need to get the zip that the customer typed and the package information in the cart (quantity, weight, height, width, length) and based on this information I will develop a specific formula. I started a basic formula just trying to get the zip, but it already caused the error I reported above.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test Shipping
Plugin URI: 
Description: 
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Wendell Christian
Author URI: 
*/

if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

function Test_Shipping_Br_init() {
    if ( ! class_exists( 'Test_Shipping_Br' ) ) {
        class Test_Shipping_Br extends WC_Shipping_Method {

            public function __construct() {
                $this->id                 = 'Test_Shipping_Br'; 
                $this->method_title       = __( 'Test Shipping Brazil' );  
                $this->method_description = __( '' ); 

                $this->enabled            = "yes"; 
                $this->title              = "Test Shipping Brazil"; 

                $this->init();
            }

            function init() {
                $this->init_form_fields();
                $this->init_settings();

                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_shipping_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            }


            public function calculate_shipping( $package ) {

                $array = WC_Cart::get_shipping_packages();                  
                $postcode = $array[0]['destination']['postcode'];


                if ($postcode >= 75960000 && $postcode <= 75969999)
                {
                    $cost = 17;

                }


                $rate = array(
                    'id' => $this->id,
                    'label' => $this->title,
                    'cost' => round($cost,2),
                    'calc_tax' => 'per_order'
                );

                $this->add_rate( $rate );
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'Test_Shipping_Br_init' );

function add_Test_Shipping_Br( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'Test_Shipping_Br';
    return $methods;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_methods', 'add_Test_Shipping_Br' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The get_items_needing_shipping seems to be missing from your plugin example.

And that's what the error implies as well.

Does the function exist?

Comment: All the plugin code is the one I posted. I am new to developing Wordpress, I could not find in the documentation a way to call the function that returns the values of the zip, weight, height, width, and length.

Comment: But the error clearly states that the method/function is missing.
If this is all the code you can safely assume that you're missing a method in your plugin. So research that and add it or make something to exclude it.

Comment: I declare `$array = WC_Cart::get_shipping_packages();` to inherit the Woocommerce method, I can not find the reason for not working.